# Libre Office Draw Alternative with infinte canvas

Tags: open-source, diagram, libreoffice, component-diagram, flowchart

I would like an offline program that similarly to LibreOffice Draw allows the drawing of simple diagrams (mostly just boxes that will be connected by arrows) with an infinite canvas that runs on linux. What are some good options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use yEd for this:

https://www.yworks.com/products/yed

Has worked very well for me.  Available for Windows, Mac, Linux, and generic Java.

TWIMC, I have no affiliation whatsoever with its developer.

Comment: Found a far better alternative: draw.io